# Can a tiefling barbarian cast Hellish Rebuke while raging?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, barbarian, tiefling

So, we have a Tiefling Barbarian in our campaign, who just gained access to Hellish Rebuke as a racial spell.  The spell states that you point at a target that has attacked you, and they catch fire.

Typically, you cannot cast spells while enraged, but this is a reaction, and has no "memorized" or "hand sign" components; can this racial spell be cast while raging?

Comment: i think what all these questions are missing is the fact that that tieflings hellish rebuke isn't reallly a spell for them, it's just a racial impulse.

Comment: Well yes, but story-wise, for barbarians raging is also not a circumstance under which you would just merely point at an opponent, even if you thought it would make them catch fire. A barbarian who is raging wants to feel the spray of their blood on his/her face.

Answer (score 29):

The rules are quite clear (emphasis mine):

> **Rage**
>
> [...] If you are able to **cast spells**, you can't cast them or concentrate on them while raging. [...]

&

> **Infernal Legacy.**
>
> [...] you can **cast** the *hellish rebuke* **spell** [...]

So by the rules, you are not able to cast any spells independent on what kind of action and components they need as long as you are raging.

Answer (score 24):

Casting Hellish Rebuke when raging is not possible.

> If you are able to cast spells, **you can't cast them** or concentrate on them while raging. (Player's Handbook, page 48, under Rage)

The casting time or source of the spell doesn't have an impact here - a raging barbarian simply can't cast spells at all.

Comment: Ah, ninja'd me!

Comment: If it were my t-barb, I'd be tempted to cast it on their corpses after the fight ends and he comes down from the rage. Just because.

Answer (score 9):

**No, they cannot cast the spell**

From the Barbarian class feature Rage..

> ... If you are able to cast spells, you can't cast them or concentrate
>   on them while raging.